# Dropdown validation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

Actually I am a new user of **LAMP**(Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP). I have created a web page using php scripts and have used sort of validation rules by **js validation plugin** to validate form inputs (textbox, email etc).

- I have created **2 dropdown list**  .

  - (a) **"Category"** contains options as **Child,Adult**
  - (b) **"Seat"** contains options as **NON-AC,AC**
- Then I have used a **text box**: **"Amount"**  which receives input as integer.
  The conditions are

  - child & Non-AC - 150 (as Amount)
  - Child & AC -200 (as Amount)
  - Adult & Non-AC - 300 (as amount)
  - Adult & AC - 400 (as amount)

I have to validate **Amount** textbox by considering the inputs form both the **dropdown** list.

I have searched for jquery validation.js and found the **min** constraint. but didn't get way to custom validation code to validate textbox using min and input from the dropdown list.

I will be very thankful , if someone helps me out.

Comment: I think this `text box: "Amount"` should be read-only thing since its value can be calculated with the previous options

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own validation method like follow

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "amountcheck",
    function(value,element){
         // value ==> the value of text box , element ==> the text box
         var category = $("#category").val();
         var seat = $("#seat").val();   
         // check it's valid or not..
         if (true){
              return this.optional(element) || true;
         }else{
              return this.optional(element) || false;
         }
    },
    "Invalid Amount"
);
```

Then

```
$(form).validation({
    rules:{
        Amount:{
             amountcheck:true
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:---

```
jQuery('#Category).change(function() {
    //ur code comes here..
    //here you can give ur condition based on category changed..
});
```